# Failed to execute script docker-compose error

Tags: python, docker

I am having trouble getting my docker-compose.yml file to run, I am running the command docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml and am getting the error "TypeError: You must specify a directory to build in path
[7264] Failed to execute script docker-compose"

The file I have this in is called Labsetup and inside the file I have
docker-compose.yml,dockerClient.yml,dokcerServer.yml,and
A file called Volumes that have Server.py and Client.py

To this point I have edit my docker-compose.yml file and tried running "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up" to run the yml below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:

    # new code to execute python scripts in /volumes
    server:
        image: 85345aa61801  # from DockerServer.yml
        container_name: server
        build: DockerServer.yml
        command: python3 ./volumes/Server.py
        ports:
          - 8080:8080

    client:
        image: 700c22b0d9d6   # from DockerClient.yml
        container_name: client
        build: DockerClient.yml
        command: python3 ./volumes/Client.py
        network_mode: host
        depends_on:
          - server

    
    # below is original code for containers
                 
    malicious-router:
        image: handsonsecurity/seed-ubuntu:large
        container_name: malicious-router-10.9.0.111
        tty: true
        cap_add:
                - ALL
        sysctls:
                - net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
                - net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
                - net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects=0
                - net.ipv4.conf.eth0.send_redirects=0
        privileged: true
        volumes:
                - ./volumes:/volumes
        networks:
            net-10.9.0.0:
                ipv4_address: 10.9.0.111
        command: bash -c "
                      ip route add 192.168.60.0/24 via 10.9.0.11 &&
                      tail -f /dev/null                 "

    HostB1:
        image: handsonsecurity/seed-ubuntu:large
        container_name: host-192.168.60.5
        tty: true
        cap_add:
                - ALL
        volumes:
                - ./volumes:/volumes
        networks:
            net-192.168.60.0:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.60.5
        command: bash -c "python3 Server.py"
                  
    HostB2:
        image: handsonsecurity/seed-ubuntu:large
        container_name: host-192.168.60.6
        tty: true
        cap_add:
                - ALL
        volumes:
                - ./volumes:/volumes
        networks:
            net-192.168.60.0:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.60.6
        command: bash -c "python3 Client.py"
                     
    HostB3:
        image: handsonsecurity/seed-ubuntu:large
        container_name: host-192.168.60.7
        tty: true
        cap_add:
                - ALL
        volumes:
                - ./volumes:/volumes
        networks:
            net-192.168.60.0:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.60.7
        command: bash -c "python3 Client.py 8080"
    Router:
        image: handsonsecurity/seed-ubuntu:large
        container_name: router
        tty: true
        cap_add:
                - ALL
        sysctls:
                - net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
        volumes:
                - ./volumes:/volumes
        networks:
            net-10.9.0.0:
                ipv4_address: 10.9.0.11
            net-192.168.60.0:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.60.11
        command: bash -c "
                      ip route del default  &&
                      ip route add default via 10.9.0.1 &&
                      tail -f /dev/null                 "

networks:
    net-192.168.60.0:
        name: net-192.168.60.0
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 192.168.60.0/24

    net-10.9.0.0:
        name: net-10.9.0.0
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 10.9.0.0/24
```

My DockerServer.yml

```
 # Dockerfile.
# FROM ubuntu:20.04 # FROM python:latest 
# ... most recent "image" created since DockerServer build = f48ea80eae5a  <-- needed in FROM

# after running command:  docker build -f DockerServer.yml .
# ... it output this upon completion ...
# ---> Running in 533f2cbd3135
# Removing intermediate container 533f2cbd3135 ---> 85345aa61801 Successfully built 85345aa61801

# FROM requires this syntax:
# FROM [--platform=<platorm>] <image> [AS <name>]
FROM python3:3.8.5 85345aa61801 AS serverImg 

ADD Server.py /volumes/

WORKDIR /volumes/
```

My DokcerClient.yml

```
# Dockerfile.
# FROM ubuntu:20.04 server # python:latest   #FROM ubuntu:latest   ?
# step1/3 image --> f48ea80eae5a   ... Successfully built 700c22b0d9d6
# image needed for 2nd arg

# after running command: docker build -f DockerClient.yml
# ... it output this upon completion ...
# Removing intermediate container 29037f3d23fb ---> 700c22b0d9d6 Successfully built 700c22b0d9d6

# FROM requires this syntax:
# FROM [--platform=<platorm>] <image> [AS <name>]
FROM python3:3.8.5 700c22b0d9d6 AS clientImg

ADD Client.py /volumes/

WORKDIR /volumes/
```

I am creating a project for a networking class that connects users to chat on a terminal. I have two python codes one being called Server.py that starts the server and tells who is in the chat room and another called Client.py that asks the user to put in a name and they will be able to chat. I am running this all on a virtual box Ubuntu20.04.

Code for Server.py

```
import socket
import _thread
import threading
from datetime import datetime


class Server():

    def __init__(self):

        # For remembering users
        self.users_table = {}

        # Create a TCP/IP socket and bind it the Socket to the port
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server_address = ('localhost', 8080)
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
        self.socket.setblocking(1)
        self.socket.listen(10)
        print('Starting up on {} port {}'.format(*self.server_address))
        self._wait_for_new_connections()

    def _wait_for_new_connections(self):
        while True:
            connection, _ = self.socket.accept()
            _thread.start_new_thread(self._on_new_client, (connection,))

    def _on_new_client(self, connection):
        try:
            # Declare the client's name
            client_name = connection.recv(64).decode('utf-8')
            self.users_table[connection] = client_name
            print(f'{self._get_current_time()} {client_name} joined the room !!')

            while True:
                data = connection.recv(64).decode('utf-8')
                if data != '':
                    self.multicast(data, owner=connection)
                else:
                    return 
        except:
            print(f'{self._get_current_time()} {client_name} left the room !!')
            self.users_table.pop(connection)
            connection.close()

    def _get_current_time(self):
        return datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    def multicast(self, message, owner=None):
        for conn in self.users_table:
            data = f'{self._get_current_time()} {self.users_table[owner]}: {message}'
            conn.sendall(bytes(data, encoding='utf-8'))  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Server()
```

Code for Client.py

```
import sys
import socket
import threading


class Client():

    def __init__(self, client_name):
        client_name = input("Choose Your Nickname:")
        # Create a TCP/IP socket and connect the socket to the port
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server_address = ('localhost', 8080)
        self.socket.connect(self.server_address)
        self.socket.setblocking(1)
        print("{} is connected to the server, you may now chat.".format(client_name))
        self.client_name = client_name
        send = threading.Thread(target=self._client_send)
        send.start()
        receive = threading.Thread(target=self._client_receive)
        receive.start()

    def _client_send(self):
        self.socket.send(bytes(self.client_name, encoding='utf-8'))  
        while True:
            try:
                c = input()
                sys.stdout.write("\x1b[1A\x1b[2K") # Delete previous line
                self.socket.send(bytes(c, encoding='utf-8')) 
            except:
                self.socket.close()
                return

    def _client_receive(self):
        while True:
            try:
                print(self.socket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8"))
            except:
                self.socket.close()
                return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client_name = sys.argv[1]
    Client(client_name)
```

Edit: I found a example online and followed it and changed a few

```
[11/26/21]seed@VM:~/.../Labsetup$ docker build -f DockerServer.yml .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  33.28kB
Step 1/3 : FROM python:latest
latest: Pulling from library/python
647acf3d48c2: Pull complete 
b02967ef0034: Pull complete 
e1ad2231829e: Pull complete 
5576ce26bf1d: Pull complete 
a66b7f31b095: Pull complete 
05189b5b2762: Pull complete 
af08e8fda0d6: Pull complete 
287d56f7527b: Pull complete 
dc0580965fb6: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:f44726de10d15558e465238b02966a8f83971fd85a4c4b95c263704e6a6012e9
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:latest
 ---> f48ea80eae5a
Step 2/3 : ADD Server.py /volumes/
 ---> df60dab46969
Step 3/3 : WORKDIR /volumes/
 ---> Running in 533f2cbd3135
Removing intermediate container 533f2cbd3135
 ---> 85345aa61801
Successfully built 85345aa61801


[11/26/21]seed@VM:~/.../Labsetup$ docker build -f DockerClient.yml .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  33.28kB
Step 1/3 : FROM python:latest
 ---> f48ea80eae5a
Step 2/3 : ADD Client.py /volumes/
 ---> 76af351c1c7a
Step 3/3 : WORKDIR /volumes/
 ---> Running in 29037f3d23fb
Removing intermediate container 29037f3d23fb
 ---> 700c22b0d9d6
Successfully built 700c22b0d9d6
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5513#issuecomment-354188216

Comment: Yeah that was the first page I went to, tired getting my files to look about the same and still ended up with the same error

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace

Comment: As the error message says, a string argument to `build:` is a directory name.  For example, if you specified `build: server`, then it would read `server/Dockerfile` (not a YAML file) and copy in source files like `server/server.py`.

Comment: (Other notable issues: the Dockerfile `FROM` syntax tries to embed the image ID, which is incorrect; the Compose file doesn't need to specify the `image:` ID or `container_name:`; you should not need to specify `command:` to override the Dockerfile `CMD`; the `client` incorrectly disables Docker networking with `network_mode: host`; the server code needs to listen on `0.0.0.0`, not `localhost`; the client code needs to connect to the Compose container's name `server` and not itself, `localhost`.)